# Spring Tool Suite Closes Automatically after adding dependency to pom.xml file

Tags: java, spring, ide, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I am trying to use Spring Data but whenever I add its dependency to pom.xml, after 5-10 seconds, STS closes automatically. If I remove the dependency, it works. But, I need to use Spring Data in my project. What should I do? Expert help needed. I'm using STS 3.7.3.RELEASE
I tried changing JDK version. I switched workspace too. I also tried to clean the project. But, problem won't fixed. This is the dependency that I tried to use. I also tried to use the latest dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the temporary solution. I just unchecked the option "Build Automatically" which is under "Project" menu.

Answer (score 0):

If it closed just after starting ,problem is with dashboard

1. goto
   sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator
   edit bundles.info and set below config to true as follow
   2.**org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui,3.8.3.201612190658-RELEASE,plugins/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui_3.8.3.201612190658-RELEASE.jar,4,true**